# Programatically set focus for material checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to programatically set focus on an Angular Material checkbox, but it is not working on angular 12 app.

Here is what I have tried.

I created a temp reference like this,

```
@ViewChild('maaz') chk:any;
```

and on a button click, I call this method:

```
this.chk.focus();
```

Here is the angular 6 application on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-focus?file=app%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.html) where focus works as reference how it should have worked.

Here is my [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqvkk8-8fjwx1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-configurable-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-configurable-example.ts,package.json) on stackblitz

Comment: What do you consider as focus? The console.logs show that the focus is on, but checkbox doesn't manifest it. Are you wishing some kind of frame on it? then it is question of styling in css

Comment: Focus is when you press tab key,  you see a style applied over the checkbox

Comment: Check my updated answer (added angular 6 app stackblitz). The style should appear by default from angular material.

Comment: SO, again it is not focus error, but you want to style checkbox on focus. It is not same. You can see in the docs, that the focusing effet is always on: https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview#checkbox-overview

Comment: This said, there is something buggy, in your demo the checkbox cannot be checked. I am unable to check Docs' stackblitz, it doesn't my safari

Comment: The implementation of `onClick` is missing from your stackblitz

Comment: I added the onclick method. it works on angular 6 apps but not on anguar 12 apps

Comment: @vega, You can check and uncheck the checkbox now. Still cannot set focus on it

Comment: You seem to have mixed up the reference. It’s the checkbox that needs the reference, currently you put it on the button.

Comment: @Andy, the focus is programmatically and correctly is going to the checkbox, at least in the demo

Comment: @anonymous, that does seem to be a bug in the new AM. The workaround I found is working almost: put the focus in the template itself: maaz.focus()

Comment: @vega, yes that's what I did.

Comment: The workaround you suggested, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in Angular latest version as Vega mentioned,

Material checkbox focus issue - https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18912

The workaround is to add the below style,

```
.mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple {
    .mat-checkbox.cdk-focused & { opacity: 0.12; }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqvkk8-knmpvf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-configurable-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-configurable-example.css)

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a bug in Angular Material 12 checkbox focusing. The way you try should have worked.
A possible workaround could be to set the focus directly from the template, using the template variable. This seems to work:

```
<mat-ckeckbox ...#maaz...></mat-checkbox>
...
<button (click)="amaze.focus()>Focus on the checkbox</button>
```

[Modified demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqvkk8-axnks5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-configurable-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-configurable-example.ts)